# Como usar xpath com selenium no python

Tags: python, dropdown, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Olá, estou iniciando nesse mundo de automatização com python e de cara já deu tudo errado rsrs.

Vamos lá, meu problema é que estou tentando fazer um clique
em um menu de um site, estou usando o "find_element(By.XPATH,'xpath')" para chegar onde quero clicar porem não estou tendo sucesso.

Esse seria o trecho do site de onde estou tentando clicar:

```
            <div id="toolBar1Collapse" class="nav-collapse collapse">
<form id="formMenuSuperior" name="formMenuSuperior" method="post" action="/siconfi/index.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="formMenuSuperior" value="formMenuSuperior" />

                    <ul id="menuSuperior" class="nav ">
                        <li class="dropdown">                           
                            <a id="drop2" href="#" role="button" style="padding: 5px 7px;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Página de apresentação"> Apresentação <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
            <li><a id="linkMenu38" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=38" title="Link para Histórico">Histórico</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu82" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=82" title="Link para Glossário">Glossário</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu21" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=21" title="Link para Apresentação">Apresentação</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu23" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=23" title="Link para Legislação">Legislação</a></li>                      
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop3" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Publicações importantes "> 
                                Publicações <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
            <li><a id="linkMenu30104" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=30104" title="Link para Dicas da Jacque">Dicas da Jacque</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu21904" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=21904" title="Link para Cartilha do Finbra">Cartilha do Finbra</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu29" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=29" title="Link para Plano de Contas">Plano de Contas</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu13703" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=13703" title="Link para Manual de Procedimentos">Manual de Procedimentos</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu42" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=42" title="Link para Instruções e Guias de Preenchimento">Instruções e Guias de Preenchimento</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu37" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=37" title="Link para Balanço do Setor Público Nacional">Balanço do Setor Público Nacional</a></li>                        
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop4" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Informações sobre a Taxonomia"> Taxonomia <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
            <li><a id="linkMenu581" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=581" title="Link para Documentação">Documentação</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu601" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=601" title="Link para Fundamentos de XBRL">Fundamentos de XBRL</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu584" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=584" title="Link para Taxonomia Siconfi">Taxonomia Siconfi</a></li>                      
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop5" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Informações sobre MSC"> Matriz de Saldos Contábeis <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
            <li><a id="linkMenu12503" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=12503" title="Link para Documentação">Documentação</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu13503" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=13503" title="Link para Dicas rápidas">Dicas rápidas</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu12302" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=12302" title="Link para Sobre a Matriz de Saldos Contábeis">Sobre a Matriz de Saldos Contábeis</a></li>                        
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop5" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Consultas"> Consultas <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
                                 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                  <a href="#">Consultar Finbra</a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                   <li><a id="formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRA" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget has-tooltip" aria-label="Contas Anuais" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('formMenuSuperior',{'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRA':'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRA'}).submit('formMenuSuperior');return false;" title="Contas Anuais">Contas Anuais</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a id="formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARGF" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget has-tooltip" aria-label="RGF" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('formMenuSuperior',{'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARGF':'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARGF'}).submit('formMenuSuperior');return false;" title="RGF">RGF</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a id="formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARREO" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget has-tooltip" aria-label="RREO" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('formMenuSuperior',{'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARREO':'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARREO'}).submit('formMenuSuperior');return false;" title="RREO">RREO</a>
                                    </li>                           
                                  </ul>
                                </li>
```

Já tentei usando este código:

```
driver.get (url) 
time.sleep (20)
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*/a[@id='drop5' and text()=' Consultas ']").click()
```

Obtive esse erro:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*/a[@id='drop5' and text()=' Consultas ']"}
```

e também tentei assim:

```
driver.get (url) 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
dropdown = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='drop5' and text()=' Consultas ']"))).click().perform()
```

esse ultimo não aparece mensagem de erro porem ficou vermelho no colab, alguém teria alguma sugestão de onde posso esta errando? qualquer contribuição será bem vinda

Comment: Já tentou com o Xpath completo? outra observação, eu não me recordo de extrair um xpath com aspas simples dentro dele. Você editou ele? Normalmente o xpath usa aspas comum dentro dele e você fecha do código com as aspas simples. 
Outro ponto, este "and" está saindo no xpath ou é você tentando colocar 2 informações dentro do mesmo elemento? como se fosse elementoA and elementoB?

Comment: Tentei com o Xpath completo extraído direto do Chrome mas não deu certo o que achei muito estranho por sinal. Em relação ao "and" seria uma tentativa de colar 2 informações pois o id=drop5 estaria sendo usado em outra tag e o que diferenciaria uma da outra seria o texto

Comment: Com certeza o xpath de uma para a outra são diferentes, mau utilize esse and. Se isso é um dropdown tenta clicar na "seta" que deve existir para abrir ele e depois um outro comando para clicar no item desejado.

Comment: Bem só para atualizar aqui, meu problema foi resolvido rodando o selenium no vscode, por algum motivo os clicks não estavam funcionando no google colab.